# Extracting one column of a text file to another when a pattern is matched

Tags: shell, unix

I have a tab-separated text file that has 4 columns of data:

```
StudentId     Student Name        GPA        Major
```

I have to write a shell command that will stores the student names that are CS majors to another file. I used `grep cs students.txt` which works to display just students that are `cs`, but I do not know how to then take just the student's names and save them to a file.

Comment: Do you mean just the column with the names? What does your input data look like exactly? Tab separated? Space separated? Do you want the header line? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: I apologize for the poor formatting. Thanks for doing that for me! I do actually have another question (Everything is spaced by tabs), but how do I only display the students whose ID doesn't starts with a 4?

Comment: For my answer, you could make the awk expression `'($4 == "cs" && $1 ~ /^[^4]/) { print $2 }'` to add that constraint.

Comment: Or `'($4 == "cs" && $1 !~ /^4/) { print $2 }'`, which is perhaps more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your input file is tab-separated (so you can have spaces in names):

```
awk -F'\t' '$4 == "cs" { print $2 }' <infile >outfile
```

This matches column 4 (major) against "cs", and prints column 2 when it is an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
grep cs students.txt | cut -f2 >file1
```

Comment: This matches `cs` even in the wrong column, ie. as part of the name.

Comment: I know, but this is just a simple assignment. I think we are supposed to disregard if the student might have a cs included in their name.

Comment: I'd hope that your professor would care more about correctness, but, well, suppose whether they do will come out in the grading.